# a common (BAD) bug in the use of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Why the output differs from the one without printing out address of px and y

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int *px = 0;
    if (1) { // Create a new inner scope
        int x = 1080;
        px = &x;
    }
    int y = 1140;
    printf("*px = %i\n", *px);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the output *px is 1080, but when I added two printf() to print out address of px and y, the output of *px is 1040. Why???

Comment: Because undefined behavior means anything could happen.

Comment: really not that common a problem once you learn how to use pointers and memory

Comment: @GarrGodfrey since I am a beginner, I just wanna know where is the mistakes and why it suffers undefined behaviour and print out the different value

Comment: px points to x. What is x when it goes out of scope? it's nothing, so px points to unused memory with undefined results

Comment: when you have `int x` inside `{ }` it means `x` only exists for the duration of those `{ }`, any attempt to access that storage after the `}` is undefined